# Show that $\sin\theta \tan\theta <2(1-\cos 3\theta )$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Show that $$\sin\theta \tan\theta <2(1-\cos 3\theta)$$ for $0<\theta<\pi/2$

MY ATTEMPT :

Let $$ t = \cos \theta $$

$$t \times E= (1-t^2) -2t(1-4t^3+3t) $$

$$t \times E= 8t^4-7t^2-2t+1 $$

After this, I'm confused about how to proceed !

Any help ? thank you

Comment: What is E here?

Comment: Maybe write $\sin^2(\theta)<2\cos(\theta)-2\cos(\theta)\cos(3\theta)$ and use $2\cos(\theta)\cos(3\theta)=\cos(2\theta)+\cos(4\theta)$?

Comment: You've to prove that the expression is negative for $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @SarGe, how? Its derivative isn't nice either

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20, I think there is an error in the question as on $0^+$ the value of the expression is positive.

Comment: @SarGe, did you try substituting $0.5$?

Comment: If $\theta$ is close to $\pi/2$, the left hand side is 'close to' infinity (because the $\cos \theta$ in the denominator is close to $0$, while the numerator is close to $1$), while the right hand side is not.  So your inequality is not valid...

Comment: How can that be?  If $\theta = \frac \pi 6$ then $2(1-\cos 3\theta)=0$ But $\sin \theta \tan \theta = \frac 12\frac 1{\sqrt 3} > 0$.

Comment: So eyeballing it I see restricting to the first quadrant that $\sin, \cos, \tan \ge 0$ and that $\sin$ spans $0$ to $1$ and is strictly increasing while $\tan$ spans $\frac 01$ to $\frac 10$ and is also strictly increasing.  The RHS starts at $2$ and $-\cos$ starts by decreasing and $2(1-\cos 3\theta)$ will decrease to $0$ when $\cos 3\theta = 1$.  That can't happen if this is to be true. Also we must have RHS $\to \infty$ which clearly doesn't happen.  Indeed if $\cos 3\theta = 1$ RHS has a max at $4$ so LHS must never exceed $4$ which it clear can do when $\cos \theta \ge \sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Will the use of identities work here?

Comment: "Will the use of identities work here?" No, because it's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As peter's comment explains, your inequality is false because $\sin(\theta)\tan(\theta)$ grows arbitrarily large as $\theta$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from the left, while the RHS of the inequality does not.

You can show this by recalling that $\cos(x)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ for *all* $x \in \mathbb{R}$, in particular, this means you get
\begin{align}
&1 \ge \cos(3\theta) \ge -1 \ \implies \ -1 \le -\cos(3\theta) \le 1 \ \\
\implies \ &0 \le 1-\cos(3\theta) \le 2  \ \implies \  0 \le 2\left(1-\cos(3\theta)\right) \le 4
\end{align}
so the RHS of your inequality is always bounded between $0$ and $4$.

As for why the LHS blows up, peter again explains that the $\cos(\theta)$ in the denominator is the culprit. You can explicitly see this by taking the limit as $\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ from the left. Doing this you get
$$
\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\sin(\theta)\tan(\theta) = \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\sin(\theta)\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} =\left[\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \sin^2(\theta) \right]\left[\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)} \right]  = (1)\left[\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)} \right]
$$
since $\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$. For the latter limit, recall that since $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, the function $\cos(\theta)$ is *positive* on this interval, and since $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =0$, in the latter limit your dividing $1$ by a *really small* positive number, which results in a *really big* positive number. Using this, you conclude that
$$
\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\sin(\theta)\tan(\theta)= \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)} = + \infty
$$

You can also visually see this if you graph the $2$ functions:

[image]

where it is clear that $\sin(\theta)\tan(\theta)$ overtakes $2\left(1-\cos(3\theta)\right)$ in the interval we're analyzing.

Answer (score 0):

As , $\lim_{ \theta\to \pi/2-} \tan(\theta) $ goes to $+\infty $, and since $\sin(\theta) $ is bounded , so as limit tends to $\pi/2- $ , $\sin(\theta) \tan(\theta) $ goes to $ +\infty $. But the right hand side function $2 (1- \cos(3\theta)) $ is bounded on $ 0 < \theta < \pi/2 $.
So, your inequality $\sin(\theta) \tan(\theta) < 2 ( 1 - \cos(3\theta)) $ is not valid on $ 0 < \theta < \pi/2 $ .